# Use Cardano’s formula to evaluate the solution of cubic equation $x^3-6x^2+3x+10=0$

Tags: cubics

A cubic equation $x^3-6x^2+3x+10=0$, the solution are $\{ -1, 2, 5 \}$. Please use Cardano’formula (it was represented in [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html)) to evaluate the cubic equation’s solution. I’m not familiar with complex number, please show me more steps. Thanks!

Comment: The first step is usually to eliminate the quadratic term by switching to $x = t + 2,$ so define the new variable $t = x - 2$ and continue.

Comment: @WillJagy thanks. $a_2=-6,a_1=3,a_0=10$, use these values, I get $D=-27,R=0, S=\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{-27}},{\ }S$ is cubic root expression, I understand Cardano’s formula, but I’m not familiar with complex number, please give me steps.